# I can not to build the project from github.com

Tags: c++, qt, github, build

I loaded the project "synkron" from: https://github.com/matus-tomlein/synkron. When build show me:

> "QMAKE_MAC_SDK can only contain short-form SDK names (eg. macosx,
>   iphoneos)".

synkron.pro:

```
...
QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.4
QMAKE_MAC_SDK = /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk
```

How it to fixed?
I work in Qt 5.2 and Mac OS 10.9
Thanks advance.

Comment: Did you even bother to look at the project file (.pro)?

Comment: It seems that the application was developed for Qt 4. In Qt 5 something about QMAKE_MAC_SDK has changed. I'm not sure what exactly. But the error message is pretty clear. Try to use `QMAKE_MAC_SDK=macosx` or just remove QMAKE_MAC_SDK from the pro file. Or try to use Qt 4 if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the Qt5 source, [sdk.prf](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/commit/71b4325?p=qt:qtbase.git;a=blob;f=mkspecs/features/mac/sdk.prf;h=955baa3ed2bd4c139c9512c978bdcaf0e74b59ff;hb=71b4325) from this [commit](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/commit/71b4325), the short form SDK names are being checked against the ones from the output of `xcodebuild -showsdks`

On my Mac, I have the following:

```
$ xcodebuild -showsdks
  OS X SDKs:
          Mac OS X 10.7                 -sdk macosx10.7
          OS X 10.8                     -sdk macosx10.8
          OS X 10.9                     -sdk macosx10.9

  iOS SDKs:
          iOS 7.1                       -sdk iphoneos7.1

  iOS Simulator SDKs:
          Simulator - iOS 7.1           -sdk iphonesimulator7.1
```

So if you want to use the 10.7 SDK, you would set `QMAKE_MAC_SDK=macosx10.7`.  This works, and I've verified it.